# Launch test cases by hand (SenTestCase)? Need to wait for some background tasks before testing

Tags: ios, multithreading, sentestingkit

I make some data loading from disk in the background.

My test should run after the runtime store has populated, but now tests runs paralel to my loading, which causes empty objects of course, so failed tests.

Any way to run the tests after my data loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try to minimise your unit tests towards synchronous tasks. Logic tests should be designed in a way that minimises the dependency on other components.

That said, you can build asynchronous tests if you insist to do so, and sometimes there are valid reasons (just not very often). 
Have a look at [SenAsyncTestCase](https://github.com/akisute/SenAsyncTestCase) - it provides a number of base classes for such tests.

Comment: Sounds cool, except this addition: "Sometimes SenAsyncTestCase doesn't print any logs nor any errors when tests failed. Breakpoints doesn't work too. Looks like this is because of how SenTestingKit runs test cases... but not sure why."

Comment: I think I make a synchronous version of my loading for testing.

Comment: I have used the above mentioned and never had any issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

I can really recommend project I've open sourced. You can write async test likes this.

```
- (void)testSomethingAsync
{
    __block BOOL jobDone = NO;

    [CEO asyncFireAllEmployes:^{
        jobDone = YES; 
    }];

    WAIT_WHILE(!jobDone, 0.2); // stalls runloop until jobDone is true
}
```

It is available here https://github.com/hfossli/AGWaitForAsyncTestHelper

Answer (score -1):

Simply do your data fetching in the `setUp` routine of your test case.

Comment: Down-vote without comment, well, thanks for taking the trouble to click.

Comment: Sorry for that, but question was for async stuff. If I trigger my async stuff in the setUp, then tests will invoked right after fire my loading, and not after the loading finished.